# How to plot a probability density distribution graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, probability

I have about 10000 floating point data, and have read them into a single row matrix.
Now I would like to plot them and show their distribution, would there be some simple functions to do that?

plot() actually plots value with respect to data number...which is not what I want

bar() is similar to what I want, but actually I would like to lower the sample rate and merge neighbor bars which are close enough (e.g. one bar for 0.50-0.55, and one bar for 0.55-0.60, etc) instead of having one single bar for every single data sample.

would there be a function to calculate this distribution by dividing the range into small steps, and outputting the prob density in each step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`hist()` would be best. It plots a histogram, with a lot of options which you can see by `doc hist`, or by checking the [Matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html). Options include a specified number of bins, or a range of bins. This will plot a histogram of 1000 normally random points, with 50 bins.

```
hist(randn(1000,1),50)
```

Comment: There's also `histc`, whic is handy if you want to specify bin _edges_. And to get the pdf, don't forget to normalize (divide by number of samples times interval width)